# Android not respecting alternative dimens file from sw600dp folder

Tags: android

My phone width is 720 pixels. It is a Samsung Galaxy Nexus from Google. Its running Android 4.2.2.

My App, I launch, and my layout gets values from dimen files in different folders.

I have a "values-sw600dp" folder but it does not get read.
Instead the values from the default "values" folder are read.

We are targeting API level 17, with minSdk of 7, eg

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

and also in the manifest file have

```
<supports-screens 
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galaxy Nexus is an `-xhdpi` device. It shortest width is less than 600dp (720px / 2 = 360dp). Hence, it will not read from an `-sw600dp` folder.

Comment: @Squonk: Thanks -- fixed! Though it won't read from an `-sw660dp` folder either... :-)

Comment: "Though it won't read from an -sw660dp folder either..." - Very true. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, what you are saying is correct, but my Galaxy Nexus is xhdpi so instead of dividing by 1.5 to get 480dp it actually needs to be divided by 2, thus 360dp is what is necessary. I will try to edit your answer.

Comment: @Cris: Others rejected your edit, but you are absolutely correct, and I have updated the answer to match. Many thanks for catching this!

Answer (score 0):

most of the time, `sw600dp` is used to describe tablets.
See The [android guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali) for more information